# Re-run multiple commands without pressing up a lot

Tags: command-history

I embarrassingly often find myself repeating a lot of previous commands. I go <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> to find the first command. <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> again for the second command. And so on.

Is there a way to step to the next command in history after re-running one? Like it would be great to do <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to re-run the last three commands.

I know about `fc`, but it's not just about the shell. I hit this in the Python interpreter and basically everywhere I type any commands.

Comment: If there is no solution, I would also be interested in learning what is the common library (?) that these shells use for input. Ctrl-R works everywhere. What implements that?

Comment: [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). The `rlwrap` command can readline-ify many commands (with various outcome).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add it to Readline only to discover half-way through that it already does this. Ctrl-O. Super awesome!

Answer (score 2):

All of this is with regards to `bash` and your shell history, I just noticed that you're perhaps asking about Python.  I hope this helps though.

If your `history` looks like:

```
1000   command A
1001   other command B
1002   yet another command C
```

You can run:
`!com`

This will run the last command that started with '`com`', you can have any number of characters (`!c` or `!command`), then follow this up with `!oth` and `!yet` to be able to run each command in sequence.

You can also run `!1000` to re-run history entry #1000, you then know `!1001` and `!1002` will run the next two commands.

Personally, if I have a series of commands that I want to run like this, I might run multiple commands as the same command, giving it a single history entry:

```
command A; other command B && yet another command C
```

Or, create an alias:

```
$ alias doThing="command A; other command B && yet another command C"
$ doThing
```

Or, a function:

```
doThing() {
  command A
  other command B && yet another command C
  # Can also use positional arguments:  echo $1
}
$ doThing
```

Given all of this, I'm not aware of being able to do exactly what you're expecting to be able to do, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! Good tips. Putting everything on one line is the best, but I rarely know ahead of time that I will want to repeat some commands.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, if you run `history` and see the three commands you want to run are numbered 1000, 1001, and 1002:

```
$ history | tail 
...
1000  echo foo
1001  echo bar 
1002  echo baz 
1003  history | tail
```

In `bash`, you can run just one of them by prefixing the line-number with a `!`.  You can also run all of them on one line separated by semi-colons:

```
$ !1000;!1001;!1002
echo foo;echo bar;echo baz
foo
bar
baz
```

NOTE: as usual when using `!` to execute command(s) from history, it first displays the command-line it is going to execute.

This probably doesn't work the same in your python interpreter, or most other programs.  It does work similarly in some other shells, with similar history features.

BTW, this combined command will now be in the history as just one line:

```
$ history | tail -2
1004  echo foo;echo bar;echo baz
1005  history | tail -2
```

and you can run it again with `!1004`.

Answer (score 0):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. You can go <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd> and then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to execute the last three commands.

As these commands are re-added to the history, you can keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to repeatedly execute this series of commands.

From the [Readline docs](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html):

> `operate-and-get-next` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>:
>
> Accept the current line for return to the calling application as if a newline had been entered, and fetch the next line relative to the current line from the history for editing. A numeric argument, if supplied, specifies the history entry to use instead of the current line.

This is a relatively recent addition, with Readline 8.1. (December 2020.)